# Scale image to fit on canvas, while maintaining aspect ratio.

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to figure out how to render an image on a canvas, changing the canvas zoom to best fit the image (to a mimum size of 50% zoom), and allowing the user to pan around the canvas to see the remainder of the image, if it didn't all fit on the screen.

I've been writing an Image cropper and I've noticed that the two problems I'm running into are that

- When the Image is too big it's cut off of the canvas.
- When the Image is too big it takes up the entire screen.

By limiting the size of the canvas and changing the zoom of the image, I should be able reduce these issues. In the event an image is still too large, you can pan around the screen. Here is an image example of what I'm looking for

[image]

Where the RED is the Canvas element, and the PINK is the Image. (Being displayed on the Canvas, and sticking out on both sides). So the user should be able to pan left, or pan right and see the parts of the image that don't fit on the screen.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it? It's possible, but you'll have to attach a bunch of events to detect when the user scrolls and update the position of the image. Why not just set the width of the canvas to the image's one and fix the whole thing with few css? Also, is there something else in the canvas?

Comment: @Kaiido - There is a crop tool that can be resized, this is for cropping an image. I'm sure I want to do this, as It's essential to my application for users to be able to crop images (Into a square).  Unfortunately most libraries are not working with Cordova right now, so I've had to work on my own solution.

Comment: Oh, my bad, of course if you have a crop tool, you already have this bunch of events. Now it should be quite easy to detetct if you're on the picture and change the x value of `drawImage(image, x, y, width, height)` accordingly to these events